# Django objects.all() can't work in aaPanel

Tags: python, django

If `objects.all()[:1000000]` it can work,but `objects.all()` it can not work,just retutn Nothing,no error
I don't know what happen，it works fine on my computer
Everyone can help me?
it's my code

```
def get_data(request):
    units=ErpWater168ShopCardset.objects.all()
    return render(request,"listall.html",locals())
```

I try use `objects.filter()` and `objects.exclude()`,they work normally,just `objects.all()` can't work

Comment: Did you override somewhere the `all` function ? Are you using a custom manager or queryset ?

Comment: Did you override somewhere the ```all``` function ? NO
Are you using a custom manager or queryset ? Queryset 
This is what confuses me, the exact same code, put into "aaPanel" has different results
Supplementary note:```objects.all()[0:]``` is not work but ```objects.all()[0:100]``` is ok

Comment: Sorry, I have something inaccurate: ```objects.filter()``` It is normal if there is a condition, but it will not work if there is no condition

Comment: What is aaPanel ? How can you tell if it works or not ? By printing `units` or by checking on the rendered page ?

Comment: Can you please show us your model?